# How to get anchor tag html

Tags: php

I'm getting an array of anchor tags like this

```
Array
  (
   [0] => "<a href = '#'> Value1 </a>"
   [1] => "<a href = '#'> Value2 </a>"
   [2] => "<a href = '#'> Value3 </a>" 
  )
```

I want to get **value1**, **value2** and **value3**, that is the **innherHtml** only in form of **Array**, how can I get this in **PHP**?

Comment: Use `strip_tags`?

Comment: Yes, but not too much familiar with that

Comment: Well, _documentation_ is available. Combine it with `array_map`, then you will get an array as result.

Answer (score 1):

In a one-line style follows. `array_map` iterates the array whereas `strip_tags` remove tags from strings like you wanted.

```php
$arr = [
    "<a href = '#'> Value1 </a>",
    "<a href = '#'> Value2 </a>",
    "<a href = '#'> Value3 </a>",
];
$result = array_map('strip_tags', $arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  Value1 
    [1] =>  Value2 
    [2] =>  Value3 
)
```

Afterwards you can also

```php
$result = array_map('trim', $result);
```

which is equivalent to:

```php
foreach ($result as $item) {
    $item = trim($item);
}
```